# date string is not updating within while true; do loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I have a simple bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

enp="$(ip route | grep "192.168.1.1" | cut -d' ' -f 3)"

while true; do
    vnstat -l -i "$enp" --style 4 --json | awk '{ print strftime("[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> raw/caching_server_network.json
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo "" >> raw/caching_server_network.json
    sleep 10
done
```

Currently, this script appends a strftime to the start of each vnstat output, and the strftime is updated on every call. Output:

```json
[04/Jan/2022:13:31:17] {"index":1012,"seconds":2024,"rx":{"ratestring":"13.59 Mbit/s","bytespersecond":1698943,"packetspersecond":15220,"bytes":3397887,"packets":30441,"totalbytes":29895276777,"totalpackets":43496469},"tx":{"ratestring":"2.81 Gbit/s","bytespersecond":350918926,"packetspersecond":233842,"bytes":701837853,"packets":467685,"totalbytes":518923724379,"totalpackets":354639132}}
[04/Jan/2022:13:31:41] {"index":1013,"seconds":2026,"rx":{"ratestring":"206.68 Mbit/s","bytespersecond":25834765,"packetspersecond":31840,"bytes":51669531,"packets":63681,"totalbytes":29946946308,"totalpackets":43560150},"tx":{"ratestring":"3.15 Gbit/s","bytespersecond":394123782,"packetspersecond":269030,"bytes":788247565,"packets":538060,"totalbytes":519711971944,"totalpackets":355177192}}
```

What I would like to do is have the datetime string have milliseconds included in it. But I am facing an issue where the date output is not updating anymore. Every call is just adding the same time to the string.

I have tried the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

enp="$(ip route | grep "192.168.1.1" | cut -d' ' -f 3)"

while true; do
    vnstat -l -i "$enp" --style 4 --json | awk '{ print "'"$(date +%F:%T.%3N)"'", $0 }' >> raw/caching_server_network.json
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo "" >> raw/caching_server_network.json
    sleep 10
done
```

Output:

```json
04/Jan/2022:13:30:11.743 {"index":975,"seconds":1950,"rx":{"ratestring":"73.04 Mbit/s","bytespersecond":9130121,"packetspersecond":25590,"bytes":18260242,"packets":51181,"totalbytes":29368713172,"totalpackets":42315654},"tx":{"ratestring":"3.90 Gbit/s","bytespersecond":486961964,"packetspersecond":326200,"bytes":973923928,"packets":652400,"totalbytes":498158299423,"totalpackets":340676257}}
04/Jan/2022:13:30:11.743 {"index":976,"seconds":1952,"rx":{"ratestring":"12.23 Mbit/s","bytespersecond":1529119,"packetspersecond":17962,"bytes":3058239,"packets":35924,"totalbytes":29371771411,"totalpackets":42351578},"tx":{"ratestring":"4.18 Gbit/s","bytespersecond":522336815,"packetspersecond":346742,"bytes":1044673631,"packets":693484,"totalbytes":499202973054,"totalpackets":341369741}}
```

Notice how the datetime in the above output is the same for both lines. How can I get the date to update with each vnstat call while using the date call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is changed for each invocation of `vnstat`, but if `vnstat` outputs multiple lines, all of them receive the same time. That's because the shell runs the `date` and inserts its output to the argument to `awk`.

To get a new timestamp for each line, you need to call the `date` from within `awk`. As I don't have `vnstat` on my machine, I created a simpler example:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

while true; do
    for i in {1..3} ; do
        echo $i
        sleep .1
    done  | awk '{ system("date +%F:%T.%3N\\  | tr -d \\\\n"); print $0 }'
    printf -- '-%.0s' {1..80}; echo ""
    sleep 1
done
```

The `tr` removes the newline after the timestamp.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick help. One last question, the system() part, does that save the date string into the $0? I am just not familiar with that call.

Comment: No, it just outputs it.

Comment: or just in the shell, since we're calling the external `date` utility anyway: `... | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "[%s] %s\n" "$(date +%F:%T.%3N)" "$line"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a shell loop and invoke one `awk`, `date`, `sleep` utility in each iteration (or worse, each line of output of each invocation of your command), I'd do the whole thing in something that can do all of that internally like `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -MTime::HiRes=gettimeofday -e '
  while (1) {
    open CMD, "-|", @ARGV;
    while (<CMD>) {
      my ($s,$us) = gettimeofday;
      printf "%s.%03d %s", strftime("%F:%T", localtime$s), $us/1000, $_
    }
    print "-" x 100 . "\n";
    sleep 10;
  }' vnstat -l -i "$enp" --style 4 --json >> file.log
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
ts_format='%D{%F:%T.%3.}'
sep=${(l[80][-])}

while true; do
  vnstat -l -i "$enp" --style 4 --json |
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      print -r ${(%)ts_format} $line
    done
  echo $sep
  zselect -t 1000 # cs
done >> file.log
```